# how can i migrate or cast the CommanBar control to new VSTO controls?

Tags: custom-controls, vsto

I want to pass the control for the new VSTO button click. 
I want to migrate this to new VSTO ribbon click. How can I do this?
I am using the ribbon.xml where i have added a onAction event

```
 onAction="Ribbon3_Click"  

 public bool Ribbon3_Click(Office.IRibbonControl control)
    {
        xsComp.myRibbon3_Click();
        return true;
    }
```

and the method I am calling is

```
  public void myRibbon3_Click(Core.CommandBarButton Ctrl, ref bool CancelDefault)
```

It is hitting the error to pass the argument. How can I do this?
I am using .net c# 4.0 VSTO addin for Office 2010.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems you have some problems with arguments. I checked my ribbon button handlers and they have a signature like this:

```
private void Button_OnClick(object sender, IRibbonControl control, bool pressed)
```

Yours only accepts the IRibbonControl. And when you call your myRibbon3_Click, you call it with no arguments while the signature tells you need to pass it two arguments.